# Creating if/else statements, and scanners based on the keyword in as string.

Tags: string, if-statement, text-files, user-input, keyword

I'm trying to have my code search for specific keywords, and based on those specific keywords create a scanner user-input prompt to replace such keywords.
For example, in the txt file:

Hi my name is < name>, What is your name? is your name < name>?

I like to eat < food>. Do you?

The program should detect the "< name>" and prompt the user to enter in a name twice for different keywords.

So far I have this:

```
// Java program to illustrate reading from Text File
// Using scanner class
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TxtOutput{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
      {
        // pass the path to the file as a parameter
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\aaron\\Documents\\TestTXT\\test.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        //Types of keywords
        //<adjective>, <plural-noun>, <place>, <noun>, <funny-noise>, <person's-name>, <job>, <CITY>, , <Color!>
        //, <Exciting-adjective>, <Interersting-Adjective>, <aDvErB>, <NUMBER>, <Plural-noun>, <body-part>, <verb>, 
        //<Number>, <verB>, <job-title>, 
        String data1 = sc.nextLine();

        if (data1.contains("<job>"));
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner (System.in);
        String job1;
        System.out.println("Enter a profession");
        job1 = user_input.next(); 
        String replacedData1 = data1.replace("<job>", job1 ); 
        System.out.println(replacedData1);
      }


}
```

The program can only detect one keyword and it has a pre-made if and else statement. Is there a way to make an if and else statement with a scanner based on the keywords such as "< name>" or "< food>" in a line?
I don't want to bombard this program with an unnecessary amount of pre-made if and else statements. I was wondering if there's a more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could search the whole data file for `<..>` keyword templates using regex, add the keywords found to a unique `Set`, and then loop over the keywords to ask for replacements. I think you like this:

I suggest specifying the keyword templates explicitly using alternations `|` in the regex like that:

`<adjective>|<plural-noun>|<place>|<noun>|<funny-noise>|<person's-name>|<job>|<CITY>|<Color!>|<Exciting-adjective>|<Interersting-Adjective>|<aDvErB>|<NUMBER>|<Plural-noun>|<body-part>|<verb>|<Number>|<verB>|<job-title>`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AGRd9X/1)

We could use a generic regex like `<[^<>]+>` but I don't know what else is in your file. Give it a try.

Putting everything together, [complete sample](https://ideone.com/uUJvAg):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
class Ideone {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
  Set < String > uniqueKeywords = new HashSet < String > ();
  final String regex = "<adjective>|<plural-noun>|<place>|<noun>|<funny-noise>|<person's-name>|<job>|<CITY>|<Color!>|<Exciting-adjective>|<Interersting-Adjective>|<aDvErB>|<NUMBER>|<Plural-noun>|<body-part>|<verb>|<Number>|<verB>|<job-title>";
  final String filecontent = "Text template containing all sorts of .. <adjective>, <plural-noun>, <place>, <noun>, <funny-noise>, <person's-name>, <job>, <CITY>, , <Color!> <Exciting-adjective>, <Interersting-Adjective>, <aDvErB>, <NUMBER>, <Plural-noun>, <body-part>, <verb>,  <Number>, <verB>, <job-title>, String data1 = sc.nextLine(); blah blah";

  final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.DOTALL);
  final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(filecontent);

  while (matcher.find()) {
   uniqueKeywords.add(matcher.group(0));
  }

  Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
  for (String keyword: uniqueKeywords) {
   System.out.println("Enter a " + keyword);
   String replacement = user_input.next();
   String replacedData1 = filecontent.replace(keyword, replacement);
   System.out.println(replacedData1);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: I used the generic regex. Thank you!